# How to draw this table layout in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

[image]

will you tell me how to this layout in blackberry. I use GridFieldManager but in that i did not get borders which separates each cell. I set boder for each field but it not look like this

Comment: no one have answer of my problem?????? is it not possible or tough question?

Comment: you can also do this by adding three horizontal field manager to one vertical field managaer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this is best link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-draw-table-in-blackberry/m-p/1472667#M186620)

This is the answer which i am expecting.Satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [TableLayouttManager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-rich-UI-layout-with-TableLayoutManager/ta-p/445299) 
The code and usage is given there.

Comment: Bhavik i got that link but i don't understand how to use it because it does not have any public void main (String []args). and also it does not contain any Field so how to do that then?plz tell me

Comment: @piya it clearly says how to use it. Its a manager so all you have to do is to `make an object of that manager in your Screen Class` and `add it in that class`. May be you can know now how to use that class. cheers :)